# Java performance of StringBuilder append chains

Tags: java, performance

In Java, if I am building a significant number of strings, is there *any* difference in performance in the following two examples?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < largeNumber; i++) {
    sb.append(var[i]);
    sb.append('=');
    sb.append(value[i]);
    sb.append(',');
}
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < largeNumber; i++) {
    sb.append(var[i]).append('=').append(value[i]).append(',');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no performance difference between the two styles.

StringBuilder returns itself from all append operations making this easy (for some) to make it clear that you are still working on the same object.

The first style is more traditional and preferred by some groups as a code *style*.

The second style is known as [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).  This is a style that is preferred by groups who prefer a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).  Also give Martin Fowler's article on the [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) a read.

Key thing to read there is the word "preferred" and "style".  Which one you use is up to you and your group.

Comment: Perfect answer..

Answer (score 1):

**There is no difference in performance.**

That said, first option is better because second one is what code stylists call a train wreck.

Read this [article on train wrecks](http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/how-many-train-wrecks-are-lurking-in-your-code/)

Comment: It does not violate the Law of Demeter.  The Law of Demeter is ***not*** "only one dot".  Each append returns back the string builder.  You can operate on that object without violating LoD.

Comment: it does not violate the law of demeter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67561/do-fluent-interfaces-violate-the-law-of-demeter

Comment: @MichaelT True. Corrected.

Comment: @jk True. Corrected.

Comment: So... why would this be considered a trainwreck?

Comment: @MichaelT Well that is the name some people call chainning mathod calls one after another with a dot. I din't invent the term.

Comment: @user1598390 the example given in the article has each working on another object further down in the hierarchy of the object.  That would rightly be called a train wreck waiting to happen.  However, having a method `do(foo) { ...; return this; }` and then `bar.do(1).do(2).do(3)` would not fall into what is described in the article.